# WinForms ListView TileSize when hosting in WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms, listview, windowsformshost

I am working on a WPF project using some WinForms user controls (to reuse code from other projects at my workplace). This works quite well by using the WindowsFormsHost control in WPF.

Recently I stumbled upon a strange case of how ListViews in Tile mode (ListView.View=Tile) are displayed when hosted in WPF. It seems like ListView.TileSize is ignored, and listview items are given a width of about 35-40 (instead of 200 which is tile size width in my test).

UserControl containing a ListView, hosted in a WPF application:
[image: ListView hosted in a WPF application]

The same UserControl, running in a WinForms application:
[image: ListView in a WinForms application]

Any thoughts for a solution to this problem?

Comment: Just use a WPF `ListBox` with a `WrapPanel`. You don't need winforms for that.

Comment: @HighCode Hi. The problem is that the Winforms listview is used deep inside another Winforms UserControl that I am hosting in WPF. I have little control over the Winforms UserControls. The example in my question is simplified just to show the ListView problem.